# identifier not being recognized in a 'with' statement using a subquery in Snowflake

Tags: sql, subquery, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, order-of-execution

so I have a table that's sort of like this:

```
DELIVERY_AREA_ID,DELIVERY_RADIUS_METERS,EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP
234sfd,4000,2020-01-01 12:19:29.719
234sfd,6500,2020-01-01 12:31:40.325
234sfd,3500,2020-01-01 12:53:10.538
234sfd,6500,2020-01-01 13:11:36.094
234sfd,3500,2020-01-01 13:32:26.754
234sfd,6500,2020-01-01 13:59:11.104
234sfd,6500,2020-01-02 07:44:16.792
234sfd,3500,2020-01-02 08:07:36.284
234sfd,6500,2020-01-02 08:54:08.014
234sfd,3500,2020-01-02 09:53:05.853
234sfd,6500,2020-01-02 10:04:39.443
234sfd,10000,2020-07-01 08:29:20.194
234sfd,3500,2020-07-03 07:50:41.782
234sfd,10000,2020-07-03 08:33:14.695
234sfd,3500,2020-07-05 07:47:05.539
234sfd,10000,2020-07-05 07:53:13.930
234sfd,3500,2020-07-05 09:18:57.688
234sfd,10000,2020-07-05 09:51:07.547
234sfd,3500,2020-07-19 18:02:14.099
```

the data is actually much more varied but yeah it follows that format.

I am trying to, in one query, in snowflake database, make a 'default delivery radius' which is just the radius by month/year that has the longest duration, and then calculate the total durations in that month that had less than this default delivery radius. currently by joining. I don't want to create new tables, I know that would be easier though.

Here is my current attempt:

```
-- Find the default delivery radius for each delivery area
WITH default_radiuses AS (
SELECT DELIVERY_AREA_ID,
       MAX(DELIVERY_RADIUS_METERS) AS default_delivery_radius,
       MONTH_YEAR,
       DELIVERY_RADIUS_METERS,
       SUM(DURATION_SECONDS) AS total_duration,
       max(EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP) as MAX_TIMESTAMP,
       RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY DELIVERY_AREA_ID, MONTH_YEAR ORDER BY total_duration DESC) AS RADIUS_RANK
FROM (
    -- Add the MONTH_YEAR column to the delivery_radius_log table
    SELECT DELIVERY_AREA_ID,
           DELIVERY_RADIUS_METERS,
           EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP,
           CONCAT(MONTH(EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP), '/', YEAR(EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP)) AS MONTH_YEAR,
           DATEADD(second, DATEDIFF(second, EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP, LEAD(EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP) OVER (PARTITION BY DELIVERY_AREA_ID ORDER BY EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP)), EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP) AS end_timestamp,
           DATEDIFF(second, EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP, LEAD(EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP) OVER (PARTITION BY DELIVERY_AREA_ID ORDER BY EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP)) AS duration_seconds
    FROM delivery_radius_log
)
GROUP BY DELIVERY_AREA_ID, MONTH_YEAR, DELIVERY_RADIUS_METERS
ORDER BY RADIUS_RANK asc, month(MAX_TIMESTAMP)
)

-- Find the duration of each radius reduction
SELECT DELIVERY_AREA_ID,
       CONCAT(MONTH(EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP), '/', YEAR(EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP)) AS MONTH_YEAR,
       DELIVERY_RADIUS_METERS,
       EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP,
       DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP, LEAD(EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP) OVER (PARTITION BY DELIVERY_AREA_ID ORDER BY EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP)), EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP) AS end_timestamp,
       DATEDIFF(hour, EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP, LEAD(EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP) OVER (PARTITION BY DELIVERY_AREA_ID ORDER BY EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP)) AS duration_hours
FROM delivery_radius_log
JOIN default_radiuses USING (DELIVERY_AREA_ID, MONTH_YEAR)
WHERE DELIVERY_RADIUS_METERS != default_delivery_radius
```

I currently get the error 'Invalid identifier MONTH_YEAR'. what can I do to resolve this?

The two queries work separately, so I guess I am just missing an order of execution thing? in my mind it works out but I'm not sure obviously

ok after some feedbacks I have added an alias, dropped the order by, but I still think I have some issues with my join:

```
-- Find the default delivery radius for each delivery area
WITH default_radiuses AS (
    SELECT DELIVERY_AREA_ID,
           MAX(DELIVERY_RADIUS_METERS) AS default_delivery_radius,
           MONTH_YEAR,
           DELIVERY_RADIUS_METERS,
           SUM(DURATION_SECONDS) AS total_duration,
           MAX(EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP) AS MAX_TIMESTAMP,
           RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY DELIVERY_AREA_ID, MONTH_YEAR
                        ORDER BY SUM(DURATION_SECONDS) DESC) AS RADIUS_RANK
    FROM (
        -- Add the MONTH_YEAR column to the delivery_radius_log table
        SELECT DELIVERY_AREA_ID,
               DELIVERY_RADIUS_METERS,
               EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP,
               CONCAT(MONTH(EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP), '/',
                      YEAR(EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP)) AS MONTH_YEAR,
               DATEADD(second, DATEDIFF(second, EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP, LEAD(EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP) OVER (PARTITION BY DELIVERY_AREA_ID ORDER BY EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP)), EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP) AS end_timestamp,
               DATEDIFF(second, EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP, LEAD(EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP) OVER (PARTITION BY DELIVERY_AREA_ID ORDER BY EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP)) AS duration_seconds
        FROM delivery_radius_log
    ) t  -- added alias here
    GROUP BY DELIVERY_AREA_ID, MONTH_YEAR, DELIVERY_RADIUS_METERS
)


-- Find the duration of each radius reduction
SELECT a.DELIVERY_AREA_ID,
       CONCAT(MONTH(EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP), '/', YEAR(EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP)) AS MONTH_YEAR,
       a.DELIVERY_RADIUS_METERS,
       EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP,
       DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP, LEAD(EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP) OVER (PARTITION BY a.DELIVERY_AREA_ID ORDER BY EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP)), EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP) AS end_timestamp,
       DATEDIFF(hour, EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP, LEAD(EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP) OVER (PARTITION BY a.DELIVERY_AREA_ID ORDER BY EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP)) AS duration_hours
FROM delivery_radius_log a
JOIN default_radiuses b on (a.DELIVERY_AREA_ID = b.DELIVERY_AREA_ID,CONCAT(MONTH(EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP), '/',
                      YEAR(EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP)) = b.MONTH_YEAR)
WHERE a.DELIVERY_RADIUS_METERS != default_delivery_radius
```

I get the error

```
Invalid data type [ROW(BOOLEAN, BOOLEAN)] for predicate [ROW(A.DELIVERY_AREA_ID = B.DELIVERY_AREA_ID, (CONCAT(CAST(EXTRACT(month from A.EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP) AS VARCHAR(16777216)), '/', CAST(EXTRACT(year from A.EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP) AS VARCHAR(16777216)))) = B.MONTH_YEAR)]
```

I don't get how there is an invalid join if I use the same method to create that field in the earlier with statement

Comment: delivery_radius_log das no column MOINTH_YEAR so you can_ä#t join it with this column.

Comment: oh ok so I could rewrite the join as 
FROM delivery_radius_log a
JOIN default_radiuses b on (DELIVERY_AREA_ID,CONCAT(MONTH(EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP), '/',
                      YEAR(EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP)) AS MONTH_YEAR = b.MONTH_YEAR)

Comment: ah ok I re-wrote it as such:
JOIN default_radiuses b
ON a.DELIVERY_AREA_ID = b.DELIVERY_AREA_ID
AND CONCAT(MONTH(EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP), '/',
           YEAR(EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP)) = b.MONTH_YEAR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every derived table/subquery requires an alias in SQL.  In addition, there is no point in using an `ORDER BY` clause in your CTE, so it should be removed.  Also, you cannot refer to the `total_duration` alias in the select in the same select in which it was defined.  Instead, just repeat the `SUM()` expression.  Making both of these changes we can try:

```sql
WITH default_radiuses AS (
    SELECT DELIVERY_AREA_ID,
           MAX(DELIVERY_RADIUS_METERS) AS default_delivery_radius,
           MONTH_YEAR,
           DELIVERY_RADIUS_METERS,
           SUM(DURATION_SECONDS) AS total_duration,
           MAX(EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP) AS MAX_TIMESTAMP,
           RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY DELIVERY_AREA_ID, MONTH_YEAR
                        ORDER BY SUM(DURATION_SECONDS) DESC) AS RADIUS_RANK
    FROM (
        -- Add the MONTH_YEAR column to the delivery_radius_log table
        SELECT DELIVERY_AREA_ID,
               DELIVERY_RADIUS_METERS,
               EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP,
               CONCAT(MONTH(EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP), '/',
                      YEAR(EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP)) AS MONTH_YEAR,
               DATEADD(second, DATEDIFF(second, EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP, LEAD(EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP) OVER (PARTITION BY DELIVERY_AREA_ID ORDER BY EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP)), EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP) AS end_timestamp,
               DATEDIFF(second, EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP, LEAD(EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP) OVER (PARTITION BY DELIVERY_AREA_ID ORDER BY EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP)) AS duration_seconds
        FROM delivery_radius_log
    ) t  -- added alias here
    GROUP BY DELIVERY_AREA_ID, MONTH_YEAR, DELIVERY_RADIUS_METERS
)

SELECT ...
-- your query here
```